# Django rest_framework_simplejwt token expiring too fast

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

With Django I've set up authentication with JWT using the rest_framework_simplejwt app.

I believe the default timeout for the access token is 1 day, and even after explicitly configuring it to 1 day in settings.py the token doesn't work anymore after ~10 minutes, and the server returns a 401 response.

**settings.py:**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'TOKEN_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=1),
    'TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME': timedelta(days=7),
}
```

I was thinking there might be a problem with the time setting in Django, so in settings.py I put a print of datetime.datetime.now(), which strangely is called twice during startapp, with a 2 hour time difference. Still though if the token lifetime is supposed to be 1 day it should be valid so I'm not sure what's the issue.

Any ideas on what the problem might be? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure you are providing right key names `settings.py`?

According to django-rest-framework-simplejwt's [repository](https://github.com/davesque/django-rest-framework-simplejwt#settings), you need to use `ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME` instead of `TOKEN_LIFETIME` and `REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME` instead of  `TOKEN_REFRESH_LIFETIME`.

Comment: Ah, yes. It seems I was reading an outdated documentation for the library.

Comment: Hello Cagrias, even after using ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME to 2 days, it is getting defaulted to 1 hour, and the strange part is that it is happening only after deployment, it works as expected when serving from local. Any heads up ?